# Host firebreath plugin in Node.js

Tags: node.js, add-on, firebreath

I have created a browser plugin based on Firebreath framework. Now I want to load the plugin into Node.js and make the javascript code communicate with the plugin. My draft idea is creating a Node.js C++ add-on to wrapper the plugin. Node.js loads the add-on. The add-on loads the plugin. The function call between the javascript code and the plugin code is via the add-on.

I want to consult the experts before moving ahead. Does anyone have the experience to make the node.js script communicate with firebreath plugin? Is my idea possible? Please share more details.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: Very beautiful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.  What I'd probably do instead is try to abstract out the JSAPI stuff (ScriptingCore project) and make an adapter that wraps a JSAPI object with a node object. Actually loading the full plugin as-is would require a lot of work. It's doable, but it would be a bit of a pain.

... I wrote FireBreath, so I do know what I'm talking about =]

Comment: Thank you, Taxilian. Your suggestion is valuable. I'm amazed to know you are the author of FireBreath. It is pretty cool and easy to use. It saves me a lot of effort to build the browser plugin.I'm appreciate your excellent work.

Comment: @taxilian Can we use this technique to replace NPAPI plugin as well?what will be challenges ?

Comment: @Chris_vr that depends on what your purpose in replacing an NPAPI plugin is.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @taxilian I need to interface with USB device in the system.Please suggest me.Will it be supported in IE,Chrome,FF,Safari?

Comment: you'd need another plugin technology for that to work.  Right now the only one supported by all of those is NPAPI.